# why does this one jquery work and the other does not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a cms and am using php to dynamically create jquery on the fly. The first below works fine when the php renders the jquery inlce in my code but the second only works if I place on my js function script which is called into the header of the page:

```
# start index video row
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo "$('#indexVid').fancybox({"; echo " \n";
    echo "'width' : '75%',"; echo " \n";
    echo "'height' : '75%',"; echo " \n";
    echo "'autoScale' : true,"; echo " \n";
    echo "'transitionIn' : 'elastic',"; echo " \n";
    echo "'transitionOut' : 'elastic',"; echo " \n";
    echo "'type' : 'iframe'"; echo " \n";
    echo "});"; echo " \n"; 
    echo '</script>';

# open help
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    echo '$("#open_testing").click( function(){ $("#info_testing").css("display","block"); } );'; echo " \n";
    echo '$("#close_testing").click( function(){ $("#info_testing").css("display","none"); } );'; echo " \n";   
    echo '</script>';


                    $name = 'testing';
            $this_label = 'Learn about Site Settings';
            $info = 'Site Settings are variable aspects of the site which are common to all or most all of the pages on the site such as copyright information and such, or they are miscellaneous variables necessary to a specific aspects of the site such as the send mail limitation. To find out more about each click on the info icon.';

            <p id="open_'.$name.'" class="info-link"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i> '.$this_label.'</p>

            <div id="info_'.$name.'" class="hide info-wrap">
            <h3>'.$this_label.'</h3>
            echo $info;
            <p class="center"><a id="close_'.$name.'" class="button small"  title="Close Info Panel">
            <i class="icon-remove-sign"> </i> Close</a></p>
            </div>
```

The html is above

```
$("#open_testing").click( function(){ $("#info_testing").css("display","block"); } );
    $("#close_testing").click( function(){ $("#info_testing").css("display","none"); } );
```

which is working if the above jquery is in the header but not if inline in the code

can some explain why? thanks

Comment: This is so painful to read. Please just post the result of this ...

Comment: Do you have any errors in your JavaScript console when the second one "doesn't work"?

Comment: I guess because second code should be wrapped in doc.ready...

Comment: @Nico O and adeneo... I join this site to learn how to be a better programmer... Oh God no!!! does not help... what would help is why Oh God no... Why is it that those who know more programming than you think they are so much better than you? both of you had to start somewhere... if you know why it is bad programming tell me or don't bother to comment.

Comment: @petebolduc you are right. you have to start somewhere. But you have to help us to help you. All we asked for, was a more readable version of your code. So if you'd just copy the html ouput after running your script and append error information of your console, if you have some, it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Don'tdo multi line echoes like that. Either break out of php mode or at least use a [heredoc](http://php.net.heredoc)

Comment: You don't need to be a good programmer in order to follow the guidelines on this page:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Great. Thank you for the edit. Now just the important HTML is missing to see which elements you target with the `click` event. Also what does not work? The click events only?

Comment: getting it now ... thank you Nico

Comment: you are very welcome. I just wonder why the edit has been reverted. What so ever, we need to see the html of #open_testing, #close_testing, #info_testing and some more information what was the expected result and what is not working.

Comment: That indicates that @nevermind was right. You need to enclose this code with a document ready function. `$(function(){ /* code here */ })`;

Comment: The original question was why does it work if in the header and not inline... and is it bad to use multiline echos as pointed out by heredoc... i do that because it minimizes the out put of the html??

Comment: @petebolduc If you think the problem is on the client-side javascript/jquery, Could you post the *HTML result* of the php in your question, and not the php? Maybe even create a http://jsfiddle.net, to make it easier to understand?

Comment: I wrapped the jquery in the doc.ready and it still did not work... but i think i have stumbled onto a major issue with my programming... I echo each line of html and allow php to parse it... is it better to write the html and only use php for the variables where needed... hope i asked that correctly